# Unable to install apps. Delete some items

Tags: android, installation

I developed a small android app. While on pc, i tried running it in BlueStacks emulator  and it works fine on that. But when I was installing it on my phone, It says "Unable to install First. Delete some items" (First is the app name)
The apk size is just 710 kb though i'm facing the memory management problem. Is there a problem in apk? How to rectify this?

Comment: This problem happens when you run the app from your IDE or when you try to execute the apk?

Comment: It runs fine on PC (through IDE as well as through apk on BlueStacks)
but when i copy the apk in my phone and try to install i face this error.

Comment: Are you using any custom rom on your phone? Also can you provide some info about your phone/android?

Comment: Don't have any custom rom. Phone has android 4.2 and my app is for 2.2 - 4.4

Comment: This is a new error for me, but I don't think the problem is in your apk, have you tried with another apk (just create a new dummy apk)? Also you can install app's from PlayStore?

Comment: I tried to install camscanner now. it directly says, aplication not installed! :/

Comment: Yeah the problems seems to be on the phone :( will be hard to help in that case

Comment: hmm okay! i'll try installing on some other phone. And comment if it works fine there